# Redirect/tunnel (Tight)VNC traffic over (Open)VPN connection? (Windows)

Tags: vpn, openvpn, vnc

**(updated routes list/OpenVPN connection data to reflect the current situation)**

This probably has been asked/answered before, but i'm really lost (and i can't comment on other/existing questions yet due to lack of points).

**What i'm trying (and want) to achieve**, is to let my remote (WAN) users connect to my VNC server, but via my (Open)VPN public/external IP address.

I know i have to add a routing entry to the routing table, but i really have no clue what to enter.

Below is some useful information about my network:

**IPCONFIG**

```
Windows IP Configuration


Ethernet adapter Ethernet:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : home
   IPv6 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : (assumebly public address)
   Temporary IPv6 Address. . . . . . : (assumebly public address)
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::71dd:e774:1c82:f1ba%12
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.227
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1

Ethernet adapter Ethernet 2:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::98a3:ea3d:644e:7bd4%10
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.9.1.54
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.252
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : (empty)
```

**(Open)VPN IP data**

- 10.9.1.53 (OpenVPN DHCP server/gateway)
- 10.9.1.54 (my local OpenVPN IP address)

**ROUTE PRINT**

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
 12...60 a4 4c 3f 52 63 ......Intel(R) 82579V Gigabit Network Connection
 10...00 ff 3c 66 f8 06 ......TAP-Windows Adapter V9
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.227     25
          0.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.9.1.53        10.9.1.54     35
         10.9.0.1  255.255.255.255        10.9.1.53        10.9.1.54     35
        10.9.1.52  255.255.255.252         On-link         10.9.1.54    291
        10.9.1.54  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.9.1.54    291
        10.9.1.55  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.9.1.54    291
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        128.0.0.0        128.0.0.0        10.9.1.53        10.9.1.54     35
  (public VPN IP)  255.255.255.255      192.168.0.1    192.168.0.227     25
      192.168.0.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.0.227    281
    192.168.0.227  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.227    281
    192.168.0.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.227    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         10.9.1.54    291
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.0.227    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         10.9.1.54    291
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.0.227    281
===========================================================================
```

**OpenVPN log:**

```
Fri May 12 04:14:30 2017 Notified TAP-Windows driver to set a DHCP IP/netmask of 10.9.1.54/255.255.255.252 on interface {3C66F806-61B1-4EE3-9874-E1BB65CDFC75} [DHCP-serv: 10.9.1.53, lease-time: 31536000]
Fri May 12 04:14:30 2017 Successful ARP Flush on interface [10] {3C66F806-61B1-4EE3-9874-E1BB65CDFC75}
Fri May 12 04:14:30 2017 do_ifconfig, tt->did_ifconfig_ipv6_setup=0
Fri May 12 04:14:30 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494555270,ASSIGN_IP,,10.9.1.54,,,,
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 TEST ROUTES: 2/2 succeeded len=1 ret=1 a=0 u/d=up
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD (public VPN address) MASK 255.255.255.255 192.168.0.1
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=25 and dwForwardType=4
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 0.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.9.1.53
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=35 and dwForwardType=4
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 128.0.0.0 MASK 128.0.0.0 10.9.1.53
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=35 and dwForwardType=4
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494555272,ADD_ROUTES,,,,,,
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 C:\Windows\system32\route.exe ADD 10.9.0.1 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.9.1.53
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 ROUTE: CreateIpForwardEntry succeeded with dwForwardMetric1=35 and dwForwardType=4
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 Route addition via IPAPI succeeded [adaptive]
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 Initialization Sequence Completed
Fri May 12 04:14:32 2017 MANAGEMENT: >STATE:1494555272,CONNECTED,SUCCESS,10.9.1.54,(public VPN address),443,192.168.0.227,3053
```

**VPNbook.com OpenVPN 'client' config that i use**

```
client
dev tun1
proto tcp
remote [obtained VPN IP address] 443
remote [obtained VPN hostname] 443
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
auth-user-pass
comp-lzo
verb 3
cipher AES-128-CBC
fast-io
pull
route-delay 2
redirect-gateway
```

**And finally some PING info:**

```
Pinging 10.9.1.54 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 10.9.1.54: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Pinging [public VPN address] with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: bytes=32 time=53ms TTL=50
```

**To recap:** I want my clients to be able to VNC to my box using my public VPN IP address or its Dynamic DNS hostname that i have set-up.

Hopefully someone has the answer and a possible solution for me.

Best regards,

**copyitright**

Comment: You don't necessarily have to set up a special route. Please edit in your OpenVPN configuration. Can you ping the device on the virtual IP? If yes: you don't need a route and should be able to connect via VNC, if no: your config is wrong.

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I'll have a look and respond back. The OpenVPN config hasn't been touched by me as i downloaded a ready2use config. Thanks for the feedback and i'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: @Lenniey I could ping my public VPN address both locally and remotely. I could also ping my VPN's local address (locally of course). VNC'ing via my public VPN address however is impossible but seems more related to how my routes are set-up. I don't know what to change in my OpenVPN config. I've read all docs but it's way beyond my understanding.

Comment: Where did you get this config from? It's not...usual. But: can you ping from your _client_ to your _local VPN-server_ IP?

Comment: The config is from VPN service _vpnbook.com_. My VNC clients aren't on the same network. They are supposed to connect over _WAN_ (internet). These clients can't ping my _local_ VPN address. - BUT, since you've mentioned my VPN config to look 'unusual', i did some digging. I found out that the used VPN config appears to be an OpenVPN '_client_' config. Though, i have no intentions acting as a VPN server myself.

Comment: Now you lost me completely. Also you show a fundamental lack of knowledge using OpenVPN. I have no idea what you are trying to achieve. vpnbook.com offers a VPN connection with which you route ALL your traffic though _their_ network / servers.

Comment: Well i'm totally sorry to not have/show the fundamental knowledge to achieve this all by myself (or even explain this better). But to give it another attempt: 'What i want to achieve, is to let my remote (WAN) users/clients connect to my VNC server, but i want the connection to be made though my OpenVPN connection.'.    So, instead of having them connect to my regular (ISP) internet connection, i want them to connect to my VNC server _via_ my VPN address (if possible).

Comment: You don't _have_ a VPN server...you are a _client_ on the VPN server of your VPN provider (vpnbook.com) to bypass any restrictions of your ISP or whatever...

Comment: I see.. does this mean there's no way to achieve the thing i want? (route/tunnel VNC traffic over my VPN connection to my local VNC server).

Comment: Again: you have no **server** , you are the **client**. No, in your setup there is no way to achieve what you want. However, you can use your box as your own VPN server using a DynDNS service to connect. Check this howto: https://community.openvpn.net/openvpn/wiki/Easy_Windows_Guide

Comment: I understand the client/server thing, and the (im)possibility of it. I was just speaking in general ;-) Thank you for the guide, i'll look into it ASAP and report back my findings :-)

Comment: I'm back. Everything went fine until the step where i had to select the VPN profile in OpenVPN and connect. The error log shows a missing _ta.key_ file which wasn't generated nor mentioned during the setup. The entry is found in server.ovpn as _tls-auth ta.key 0 # This file is secret_. - After doing some research i've decided to comment it out. I still see my ISP obtained IP address though.

Comment: I assumed it was possible to tunnel VNC traffic over VPN and not expose my real IP address at the same time.

Comment: Your ISP address will always be visible if you don't use a proxy or whatever. If you got your server up and running, you connect your VPN clients to this said server's public IP (or DynDNS hostname) and then connect your VNC-client to the VNC server.

Comment: Then there's a lot more work to be done than i would've hoped for. I don't want to bother you with more newbie questions, so i guess this is the point where it ends for me, question wise. I can be wrong, but i also doubt there are any good/free Windows solutions for this proxy stuff (can only think of NGINX). Your help means a lot to me so thank you for everything! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Great to see your working with Tight VNC.

I was running with Ultra VNC in my user's machine and connect them while I was working in the home.

I connect with Open VPN, I will just use VNC clients such as tight VNC viewer or Ultra VNC viewer.

I just put the IP of the user I want to connect as like I was in office.

I can access the office network.

So, there is no requirement for adding routing table.

Please refine your Tight VNC server in the machine, check the firewall ports that 5900 and 5901 is allowed.

If you find any other issue, or the same issue exists please don't hesitate to ask me back.

Thanks and regards,

Sathiya Moorthy K

Comment: I've removed my previous comment as i overlooked the third sentence about OpenVPN. All the necessary/required ports are allowed/not blocked. I have the slightest idea why it won't work for me.

Comment: I strongly recommend you to go with Single Click of Ultra VNC.I just worked 8 months before and achieved the project by connecting my clients to my system globally.As the single click is open source, there will be no proper documentation for proceeding.

Comment: Thanks. But what version should i download (all versions appear old/outdated to me)? Also the website states "Size: UltraVNC is about 650k while SC is only 166k", but after downloading and opening some archives, filesizes are over 1MB, instead of the advertised 166k.